# Running rails from a different bundle folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundler

For debugging purposes, I installed bundle gems into a different folder

```
bundle install --path=.bundle
```

I want to debug the app modifying the gem sources in this folder, so I need to run my server, and tell rails to use the gems in the special folder

What options do I need to add to `rails server` in order to produce the desired magic?

How do you do when you need to debug a problem or a mysterious, cryptic behaviour in your rails app that doesn't seem to be due to your codebase?
More precisely, what is the recommended strategy for debugging a gem?